# How to change the style of this button in ion-calendar

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic5

[I wanna style this `ion-calendar` inbuilt classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ear9j.png)

I am adding style to the `ion-calendar-month` but nothing happens.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You could use [Stacblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to quickly create one!

Answer (score 0):

Since the style is "deep" inside the `ion-calendar` component you will need to add the style to your global stylesheet or alternatively use the `::ng-deep` selector inside your local `*.component.css` stylesheet in case you want to only override the style only locally.

Something like:

```
:host ::ng-deep ion-calendar ion-calendar-month {
  /* your custom style changes here */
}
```

`::ng-deep` promotes the style to a global style. Read more on this topic [here in the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#component-styling-best-practices).

I recommend you to add more details or a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) (also suggested by @Cuzy in his comment) to your question in case this answer doesn't resolve your problem.
I use `:host` in this example to prevent it from leaking to all calendar items.